# Young Pyromancer stacking with Village Rites

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So i am not too sure how to word this during a paper match. Let's say I have [Young Pyromancer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Young%20Pyromancer) already on the battlefield and I cast [Village Rites](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Village%20Rites). Would Young Pyromancer's ability go on top of the stack and create the Elemental first which I can then can use as part of the casting cost of Village Rites?

Answer (score 11):

No.

Sacrificing a creature is part of the *cost* of casting Village Rites:

> As an additional cost to cast this spell, sacrifice a creature.

Costs are paid as part of casting the spell and so must all be paid *before* the spell is cast and Young Pyromancer's ability triggers.

Answer (score 4):

No.

> 701.4a To cast a spell is to take it from the zone it's in (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect.

I think Philip Kendall's use of the word "before" is unclear. Paying costs doesn't happen before casting a spell, it happens *during*. Paying the costs is part of what it means to cast a spell. Taking the card from the hand, putting it on the stack, and paying the costs are all one game event called "casting". Young Pyromancer's ability is a triggered ability. Triggered abilities don't immediately perform the effect listed, they just put the effect on the stack. When you cast the spell, Pyromancer's ability doesn't create a token:

> 603.2. Whenever a game event or game state matches a triggered ability’s trigger event, that ability automatically triggers. The ability doesn’t do anything at this point.

Instead, it puts "create a token" on the stack:

> 603.3. Once an ability has triggered, its controller puts it on the stack as an object that’s not a card the next time a player would receive priority. See rule 117, “Timing and Priority.” The ability becomes the topmost object on the stack. It has the text of the ability that created it, and no other characteristics. It remains on the stack until it’s countered, it resolves, a rule causes it to be removed from the stack, or an effect moves it elsewhere.

By the time "create a token" resolves and you create a token, the action of casting the spell (including paying the costs) has been completed, and the spell is already on the stack. You do create the token before the spell resolves, but not before you pay the costs.

Comment: Re "*Philip Kendall's answer is not quite right. Paying costs doesn't happen before casting a spell, it happens during.*", They said it happens during the casting. "Costs are paid as part of casting the spell". Contrary to your claim, they did not say "before casting a spell". They did say "before the spell is cast", which means before it's finished being cast. More importantly, it also means before the occurrence of the "spell is cast" event on which Young Pyromancer's ability triggers. Their answer is actually "quite right", and you should remove this incorrect passage from your answer.

Comment: @ikegami Your reading requires "cast" being read as a past participle, rather than passive voice. Looking at the larger context of the question, and of course knowing the correct answer, the participle reading is suggested, but I think that the ordinary primary reading is passive voice. So I've modified my answer from "not quite correct" to "unclear".

Comment: Re "*Your reading requires*", It does. That's the point. The answer is explaining the wording on the card, and that's the wording on the card. There's only one way you're allowed to read it, which is to say one is required to read it that way. // Re "*Looking at the larger context of the question*", That's absolutely not needed. The answer clearly says it happens during casting ("Costs are paid as part of casting the spell"), so an interpretation that also says it happens before casting is clearly incorrect. The answer is self-contained.